# Using 2 different data to show in chart laravel

Tags: php, laravel, charts

I am currently using chartTV to create a chart but my chart doesn't seem to appear inside my blade for some reason, the title can be seen but not the graph. I want to create an areaspline chart where it will show number of people hired and not hired this week. I tried doing something like this but it not working. Can someone guide me in doing it correctly? How should I do it?

My **dashboardController**:

```
$user1s = DB::table('evaluations')
             ->select('evaluations.Evaluation_Status','evaluations.created_at' ) 
             ->where('Evaluation_Status', '=', 'No') 
             ->get();
$user2s = DB::table('evaluations')
             ->select('evaluations.Evaluation_Status','evaluations.created_at' ) 
             ->where('evaluations.Evaluation_Status', '=', 'Yes') 
             ->get();

Charts::Database($user1s, $user2s, 'areaspline', 'highcharts')
       ->title('My nice chart')
       ->labels(['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday','Saturday', 'Sunday'])
       ->dataset('Hired', [$user1s])
       ->dataset('Not Hired', [$user2s]);

return view('dashboard', ['chart' => $chart]);
```

My **dashboard.blade.php**

```
{!! Charts::assets() !!}
{!! $chart->render() !!}
```

Comment: which chart plugin do you use?

Comment: https://erik.cat/projects/Charts/docs/5 , I am using ChartTV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multi database charts can be used if using data from different database tables. The APIs are similar to Charts::multi. The only differentiation is how datasets are specified.

```
$charts = Charts::multiDatabase('areaspline', 'highcharts')
            ->title('My nice chart')
            ->colors(['#ff0000', '#ffffff'])
            ->labels(['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday','Saturday', 'Sunday'])
            ->dataset('Hired', $user1s)
            ->dataset('Not Hired', $user2s);
```

Comment: Sorry just now I edited the question, changed it back already

Comment: I just tried your code but only the title appeared, it like the chart is there but invisible

Comment: Can you try using a different color other than white?

Comment: It not the color problem, it just the graph it is not there, but I tried changing the color also and it doesn't happen. Do you want me to put a screenshot of it in my question ?

Comment: Ok I found out the problem was from the date that why it was blank, thank you for your help :)

Comment: Thank you, @Dkna. What date are you referring to? The labels?

Comment: I used this, ->lastByDay(7,'true');, but I am trying to make it show weekly and I don't know how? I check the docs they didn't say anything about it so I just did like this

Answer (score 0):

I assume the problem are these 2 lines:

```
->dataset('Hired', [$user1s])
->dataset('Not Hired',  [$user2s]);
```

Both `$user1s` and `$user2s` are already arrays. Since both array contain objects you also might have to map them to scalar values (numbers or strings) to get the values you want to use.

So you could do something like this, if you want to map the names:

```
$hiredUsernames = array_map(
    function ($user) {
        return $user->name;
    },
    $user1s
);
// The result will be something like: ['Max', 'Jane', ...]

->dataset('Hired', $hiredUsernames)
```

Comment: Oh no, I am sorry I just edited the question, will change it back to match your answer

Comment: I am sorry I am quite confused with your answer, where do I put the $hiredUserNames part?

Comment: I want to show the number of people hired and not hired, i think your answer is showing their name right?

Comment: I see the other answer already is approved, so I guess this is solved. But for completeness this was supposed to go right before building the chart

Comment: Ohh I see but just asking when I do this do I also do it for user2?

Comment: Yes, for both. I was just putting this snippet in there as an example of what it could look like, since I didn't know which data you need from the object.