# Laravel 5.5 Console TV Bar Chart High Charts multipleDatasets and label

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, charts, highcharts

I have a **Laravel 5.5** app that used this [ConsoleTV Chart Package](https://github.com/ConsoleTVs/Charts) I used a **barchart** to visualize my **data** in a **monthly report basis**. I have the following query below.

```
$dt = Carbon::now()->year;
        $anRequest = AnalysisRequest::where(DB::raw("(DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%Y'))"),date('Y'))->orderBy('service_id') 
                        ->get();
```

and in my **chart**

```
$barChart = Charts::database($anRequest, 'bar', 'highcharts')
                  ->title("Monthly service request")
                  ->elementLabel("Total requests")
                  ->dimensions(1000, 500)
                  ->responsive(false)
                  ->groupByMonth(date('Y'), true);
```

This code is working perfectly fine and display all the data in by **month** but how can I add another `dataSets` or `multipleDataSets` instead of just having one **sets of data** to **visualize**.

For example I will have another query from the **AnalysisRequest** but with a specific **resources**.

Sample code below using **multi**

The **query**

```
 $tags_jan = DB::table('tags')->whereYear('created_at', $dt)->whereMonth('created_at', '1')->count();

         $tags_feb = DB::table('tags')->whereYear('created_at', $dt)->whereMonth('created_at', '2')->count();

         $tags_mar = DB::table('tags')->whereYear('created_at', $dt)->whereMonth('created_at', '3')->count();
// and the list goes on which is bad
```

The **charts** using **multi**

```
$chart = Charts::multi('bar', 'highcharts')
            // Setup the chart settings
            ->title("Total Reports for this year")
            // A dimension of 0 means it will take 100% of the space
            ->dimensions(0, 400) // Width x Height
            // This defines a preset of colors already done:)
            // ->template("material")
            // ->responsive(true)
            // You could always set them manually
            // ->colors(['#2196F3', '#F44336', '#FFC107'])
            // Setup the diferent datasets (this is a multi chart)
            ->colors(['green', 'aqua', 'red', 'yellow'])
            ->dataset('Ads', [$ads_jan,$ads_feb,$ads_mar,$ads_apr,$ads_may,$ads_june,$ads_july,$ads_aug,$ads_sept,$ads_oct,$ads_nov,$ads_dec])

            ->dataset('Channels', [$channels_jan,$channels_feb,$channels_mar,$channels_apr,$channels_may,$channels_june,$channels_july,$channels_aug,$channels_sept,$channels_oct,$channels_nov,$channels_dec])

            ->dataset('Shows', [$shows_jan,$shows_feb,$shows_mar,$shows_apr,$shows_may,$shows_june,$shows_july,$shows_aug,$shows_sept,$shows_oct,$shows_nov,$shows_dec])

            ->dataset('Tags', [$tags_jan,$tags_feb,$tags_mar,$tags_apr,$tags_may,$tags_june,$tags_july,$tags_aug,$tags_sept,$tags_oct,$tags_nov,$tags_dec])
```

This code above also works fine but as you can see in the **variable** I am querying for each month for this year which is isn't quite good. How can I simplified this **query** or another way to solve this using multiple **dataSets**?

Appreciate if someone could help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem is not directly related with Highcharts library, but with the structure of your data. I'm not the expert of PHP, but I guess you need to pass whole series object in `->dataset()`.

Comment: @daniel_s yea that's why I asked if how can I simplified my data structure which is complicated base on my query. Anyway I already find the solution for the multiple **datasets** right [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47690319/using-2-different-data-to-show-in-chart-laravel). But I am still finding a way how to simplify my query base on monthly order.

Answer (score 0):

The following code can be added after you have queried your database and you would like to post different graphs to the same view, I was using the code to plot a barchart and line chart on the same graph as specified below........ look at the dataset position 2 its line and bar

```
$chart = new unclaimed;
$chart->labels( $days );
$chart->dataset('Daily Visitors Bar', 'bar', $totalNumber )->color('white')->backgroundColor(['#009900','#8a8a5c','#f1c40f','#e67e22','#16a085','#2980b9']);

$chart->dataset('Daily Visitors Line', 'line', $totalNumber )->color('black') ->fill(false)->backgroundColor(['##8a8a5c','009900','#f1c40f','#e67e22','#16a085','#2980b9']);
```

Comment: The code here is poorly formated if you can use your code editor will look great